# Vue beforeEach() doesn't redirect to the desired page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to redirect/continue to a certain page using vue router, After a user signs up with email and password they should be redirected to another page but the home page just gets reloaded.
I'm not implementing login at the moment, Just the signup part. Every example that I follow works fine in redirecting with just "next()"

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import Admin from "../views/Admin.vue";
import Overview from "../views/Overview.vue";
import Products from "../views/Products.vue";
import Orders from "../views/Orders.vue";
import { fb } from "../firebase";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

// The 'name' property hasn't been utilized yet

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: "/admin",
    name: "admin",
    component: Admin,
    // By adding 'requiresAuth' we ensure this route/page and it's children will not be
    // accessable by someone who is not authenticated
    meta:{ requiresAuth: true },
    children:[
      {
        // Don't put the '/' here
        path: "overview",
        name: "overview",
        component: Overview
      },
      {
        // Don't put the '/' here
        path: "products",
        name: "products",
        component: Products
      },
      {
        // Don't put the '/' here
        path: "orders",
        name: "orders",
        component: Orders
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "About",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/About.vue")
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
});

// ============= This is the method in question ==============
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(x => x.meta.requiresAuth);
  const currentUser = fb.auth().currentUser;

  // This condition always passes, Even after the user is registered, So it always reloads
  // the home page
  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
    next('/');
  // This never runs
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

export default router;
```

Comment: Did you try to log out what the currentUser is when a user logs in?

Comment: Try to console what you are getting in the variable currentUser.

Comment: I did, I get null, I'm I messing something here ?

Comment: From firebase docs, currentUser returns "The currently signed-in user (or null).". So if your user is just registered but not signed in you will get null.

Comment: @IgorMoraru I'm not signing-in the user currently, Just registering them and immediately after registration want them to be redirected to the '/admin' page. That's possible using vue or it dosen't makes sense ?

Comment: I guess your setup should work and will makes sense only after you will implement sign-in in your app.

Comment: @IgorMoraru
And others, I can't add you here
Thanks for your efforts, Wish you well :)